# Is it a bad behavior in Java to pass an object as a method argument and modify that object in that method and keep tracking that object values?

Tags: java, recursion, pass-by-reference

For example, I want to have a recursive calls of the `getChildPar`, and I want the method to modify the `int[] par` during the calls:

So in main method, I defined:

```
int[] par = new int[m * n];
```

and then in the main method calls:

```
int childPar = getChildPar(par, childIdx);
```

The getChildPar is defined as:

```
int getChildPar(int[] par, int childIdx) {
    if(par[childIdx] == childIdx) {
        return childIdx;
    }

    return par[childIdx] = getChildPar(par, par[childIdx]);
}
```

So the `getChildPar` keeps modifying the `int[] par` inside the method. I know this is kind of method implementation is quite common in C++, but not sure if it is considered bad behavior in Java?

Comment: Do you know why it is common in C/C++?

Comment: Pass the object in and modify it, I see lots of code in the company wrote like this

Comment: Again: Do you know why this kind of programming is common in C (C++ not so much, at least, In C++ there are other ways to do this)?

Comment: Off topic: Presumably, `getChildPar` is a `static` method.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks. I think it's handy this way to modify an object along with the method call. What the other option could be? Creating a member variable?

Comment: @lightrek We see this pattern in C, because C does not have an concept of exceptions. Hence, the return value is often used as a status code. If possible, I would always advice to try and treat parameters as immutable,  create a copy to work on and return the copy. In the given case, this could mean returning an aggregate object, holding the value returned, as well as the modified array. I would only advice to modify the parameter if the creating duplicates is an issue, e.g .too time- or memory-consuming.

Comment: The code, you provided, relates to [Union-Find Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-disjoint-set-data-structure-or-union-find-algorithm/), so, it looks good as a part of particular algorithm.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks! but in my example, if returning new modified `int[] par` from the `getChildPar` call, then we need multiple copies of the `int[] par` which is bad considering performance. Moreover, how to write this recursive method without modifying the passed in argument?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Yes, I tried to implement the Union Find algorithm